# Tiles and product information

Tags: usability, layout, visual-design, listview

I am working on the redesign of a page that has a number of product “tiles”; the information relating to each of the items is quite dense for example:  start and end date, notifications, status, editable or non-editable, brief description of the item its self, CTA, product image.

I would like know if there are any resources or best practices to guide me through? How many pieces of information can we display at any given time (excluding the product description)  would greatly appreciate your help. Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you will find a simple, clear answer to this query. You need to display as much information as absolutely necessary for *your* users to make an informed decision.

Don't forget that there is a lot of UI techniques you can use to minimise the visual load of the information. (IE use of colour for status - traffic light style system).

What you don't want to do is hide any information that is integral to your users decision making. You need to experiment with what your users will accept / need.

Get something online and start A/B testing sooner, instead of trying to create a foolproof design.

Comment: The only issue with colour is that it might be perceived differently by some users. the issue will be compounded when dealing with even more items - more colors. I am very much in favor of minimizing the load by using different states and supplement with relevant icons and labels. i think you are right i should start experimenting and see what works. I also agree no design is foolproof... Thank you